# Internationalization sitemesh

Tags: spring, internationalization, freemarker, sitemesh

I'm using freemarker, SiteMesh and Spring framework.
For the pages I use ${requestContext.getMessage()} to get the message from message.properties. But for the decorators this doesn't work. How should I do to get the internationalization working for sitemesh?

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "doesn't work"? Are you getting a specific error message? Does it return a random page from the Encyclopaedia Britannica instead of the message you wanted? Does it quit? Does it hang? Does it summon Yog Sothoth?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the ***fmt*** taglib.

First, add the taglib for sitemesh and fmt on the fisrt line of the decorator.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="decorator" uri="http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/decorator"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="page" uri="http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/page"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt"%>
<fmt:setBundle basename="messages" />
```

In my example, the i18n file is messages.properties. Then you need to use the fmt tag to use the mesages.

```
<fmt:message key="key_of_message" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer templates and the freemarker servlet instead you can enter the following in your templates:

```
<#assign fmt=JspTaglibs["http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt"]>
<@fmt.message key="webapp.name" />
```

and in your `web.xml`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>messages</param-value>
</context-param>
```